# How do you change the text cursor height and thickness?

Tags: themes, customize

I would like to change the shape of the cursor to something like the following image:

[image]

It's a bit taller and thicker than the default one.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the value of `cursor-type`:

> Documentation:
>   Cursor to use when this buffer is in the selected window.
>   Values are interpreted as follows:
>
> `t`        use the cursor specified for the frame
>
> `nil`          don't display a cursor
>
> `box`          display a filled box cursor
>
> `hollow`   display a hollow box cursor
>
> `bar`          display a vertical bar cursor with default width
>
> `(bar . WIDTH)`    display a vertical bar cursor with width WIDTH
>
> `hbar`         display a horizontal bar cursor with default height
>
> `(hbar . HEIGHT)` display a horizontal bar cursor with height HEIGHT
>
> ANYTHING ELSE      display a hollow box cursor

It looks like you want something like `(setf cursor-type 'bar)`

Comment: Why do `setf`? `(setq cursor-type '(bar . 4))` works just fine. *I am asking because I don't know why one would do `setf` instead of `setq`; and I have never used `setf` :).*

Comment: @kaushalmodi: they're equivalent here; `setf` is actually a macro that will expand into `setq` in this situation.  I had been learning Common Lisp, where `setf` is used pervasively, and now use it when my mind's on auto-pilot.

Comment: @Dan, I also use `setf` in Common Lisp, but it would be more idiomatic to use `setq` in Emacs Lisp. There is no difference of course, but people are generally expecting `setq`, so `setf` may confuse some people without Common Lisp background. For example, I love functional programming, but when I need to do Python, I will write `[x for x in S if P(x)]` instead of `filter(P, S)` -- which is clearer, no matter what creator of Python thinks :-D

Comment: I would use `setf` only when it's really useful, i.e. when its argument is some compound structure. But even in that case, `setcar` may be better than `(setf (car ...) ...)` in Emacs Lisp.

Comment: This answer only explains how one can widen the bar not make it taller.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like, to change both width and color

```
(setq evil-insert-state-cursor '((bar . 4 ) "orange" ))
```